# Centos 7 - Can't download RPM (Trying to connect with IPV6)

Tags: centos, rpm, curl, ipv6

I am normally an Debian/Ubuntu guy, but I wanted to test the foreman on CentOS 7, but I am having some trouble with the `rpm` command. I have tried to disable IPV6 with

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/disable_ipv6
sysctl -p
```

But nothing seems to work?

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fedb:6b1d: Network is unreachable
error: skipping http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm - transfer failed
```

Answer (score 1):

(The usual warning about **DON'T DISABLE IPV6** applies...)

This is quite strange, as the IPv6 address in question is at some Linode, while yum.puppetlabs.com is (and AFAIK was at the time) distributed via Amazon CloudFront, and has no IPv6 addresses.

```
$ host yum.puppetlabs.com
yum.puppetlabs.com is an alias for yum.puppet.com.
yum.puppet.com is an alias for d1ge15oq8tiwk1.cloudfront.net.
d1ge15oq8tiwk1.cloudfront.net has address 13.33.115.130
d1ge15oq8tiwk1.cloudfront.net has address 13.33.115.43
d1ge15oq8tiwk1.cloudfront.net has address 13.33.115.18
d1ge15oq8tiwk1.cloudfront.net has address 13.33.115.56
d1ge15oq8tiwk1.cloudfront.net has address 13.33.115.168
d1ge15oq8tiwk1.cloudfront.net has address 13.33.115.60
d1ge15oq8tiwk1.cloudfront.net has address 13.33.115.238
d1ge15oq8tiwk1.cloudfront.net has address 13.33.115.162
```

I suspect something with your local setup was feeding you an invalid address when your system attempted to do this name resolution. This most likely was something in the `/etc/hosts` file or possibly a malicious (or misconfigured) DNS server.